# Count Childs and partition by GrandParent, that resides in an unpivoted hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to show the COUNT on every row how many BuildingID's there are within the MainGroundID's, while having to deal with a parent-child hierarchy that is unpivoted.

Unfortunately there is no logic within the way the GroundID and MainGroundID's are written (although it looks that way in my example, since I made an example dataset).

```
PMEBuilding 
BuildingID, GroundID
1,          100
2,          100
3,          101
4,          201
5,          201
6,          201
7,          202
```

In reality the above table has 34K rows and 80+ fields.

The GroundID from the table above is N:1 to the table below via GroundID. 
Within the PMEGroudn table Some GroundID's refer to a certain MainGroundID, which in turn also refer to Parents higher up in the hierarchy. The 'GrandParents' are those that have a NULL value as GroundID.

```
PMEGround   
GroundID,    MainGroundID
1,           NULL --GrandParent
10,          1
100,         10
101,         10
2,           NULL --GrandParent
20,          2
201,         20
202,         20
```

In reality the above table has 2K rows of which around 500 'GrandParents'.

I want this to be the end result:

```
MainGroundID    MainGroundBuildingCount
1,              3
2,              7
```

The following code is what I used so far, but it doesn't work entirely yet:

```
;WITH UNPIVOT_HIERARCHY AS (
    SELECT GROUNDID
        ,MAINGROUNDID 
        ,PathID         = CAST(GROUNDID AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM    PMEGROUND
    WHERE   NULLIF(MainGroundID, '') IS NULL
    UNION   All
    SELECT  GROUNDID    = r.GROUNDID
        ,MAINGROUNDID   = r.MAINGROUNDID 
        ,PathID         = p.PathID+CONCAT(',',CAST(r.GROUNDID AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
    FROM   PMEGROUND r
    JOIN   UNPIVOT_HIERARCHY p ON r.MAINGROUNDID  = p.GROUNDID
)
SELECT
    B.Lvl3  AS 'MainGroundID' --This is the GrandParent, which works fine
    ,COUNT(PMEBUILDING.GROUNDID) OVER (PARTITION BY B.Lvl3) AS 'MainGroundCountBuildings'
FROM PMEGROUND
LEFT JOIN UNPIVOT_HIERARCHY
    ON UNPIVOT_HIERARCHY.GROUNDID = PMEGROUND.GROUNDID
LEFT JOIN PMEBUILDING
    ON PMEBUILDING.GROUNDID = PMEGROUND.GROUNDID
CROSS Apply (
            SELECT Lvl1 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(50)')
                  ,Lvl2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(50)')
                  ,Lvl3 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(50)')
                  ,Lvl4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(50)')
            FROM  ( VALUES (CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(PathID,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' AS xml))) B(xDim)
         ) B
GROUP BY B.Lvl3, PMEBUILDING.GROUNDID
```

Without the `GROUP BY` it gives duplicate MainGroundIDs, but the correct count.
With the `GROUP BY` it still gives duplicate MainGroundIDs but less, but the count is messed up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want this to be the end result:
>
> ```
> MainGroundID    MainGroundBuildingCount
> 1,              3
> 2,              7
> ```

Don't you mean the end result should be?

```
MainGroundID    MainGroundBuildingCount
1,              3
2,              4
```

Assuming, based on the given data, that there are 3 levels of hierarchy and PMEBuilding.GroundID contains only grandchildren I would use the following to achieve the end result:

```
select 
    gp.GroundID, count(distinct b.BuildingID)
from PMEGround gp
join PMEGround p on p.MainGroundID = gp.GRoundID
join PMEGround c on c.MainGroundID = p.GRoundID

join PMEBuilding b on b.GroundID = c.GroundID
where gp.MainGroundID is null
group by gp.GroundID
order by 1
```